# Installing Citadel on Openshift

Tags: root, openshift

Can I install [Citadel](http://www.citadel.org/) on Openshift? Installation process requires having root privileges but OpenShift does not provide such [service](https://www.openshift.com/forums/flex/root-access-in-openshift-flex-accounts). Is there any workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not install anything that requires root access.  Sometimes you can workaround by installing things to your app-root/data directory.

Answer (score 0):

OCP uses SCC which by default would be responsible to allocate random UID's for your applications pods, however, incase of particular apps needing specific UID or root as in your case, we can use SCC ANYUID instead of default RESTRICTED SCC. However, this is only possible to be done with cluster-admin privileges.